# How to access a mysql database that is into a Docker continer?

Tags: mysql, docker, boot2docker

I'm working in a windows environment and I have my MySQL database into a Docker container, but how I should access from an external application?

Right now I'm just want to use a regular Java Class to test the connection but what address should I use? I've tried with the **boot2docker ip**, but that doesn't work. I've also tried with the ip that I got with the **docker inspect** command but I haven't got any result.

```
[
{
    "Id": "ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16",
    "Created": "2015-08-11T16:07:44.597618319Z",
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mysqld"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 2167,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2015-08-11T16:38:38.256276665Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2015-08-11T16:38:08.508576127Z"
    },
    "Image": "a128139aadf282a10ec937a60010f837fa1b91dd367e05c7ca6197a84b3115b3",
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "EndpointID": "a6e0a25891c065dc47b9dccb19c89e0ab7ee358a2b7cf947f6385bb47b99bac4",
        "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.5",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:05",
        "NetworkID": "5c8e21999516c552412027ab316d3a8d8d813952fb207c1de9ec38040895fc50",
        "PortMapping": null,
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": null
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/ee02d1e46305",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null
    },
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16/ee02d1e463056c8dcd878fa7d9746c39b4377e051d11a8853be274b206b73c16-json.log",
    "Name": "/fluxtream",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "Volumes": {
        "/var/lib/mysql": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/5a05900d9551d22235e51a7d03a7354156fce1bdea3e7378f52df8d33fee1f4f/_data"
    },
    "VolumesRW": {
        "/var/lib/mysql": true
    },
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "8fd70881d9cfed795dfb6850d513e54490432fd1e55e8bf8f6040f71cc1e7a4c",
        "d3ca3e35de0222127c7e5da3e6ab45157cb06f5716c0c2bbfdc9a7096230786d",
        "b75620585c02840a62169bc5adf0a5a80fa265194ac74136c54dc31cf9edd653",
        "a61e680448ad796b1ad113776c5ba46f3b8a03f6601d843b005722748c9d5669"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "bridge",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": ""
    },
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "ee02d1e46305",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "PortSpecs": null,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=fluxtream",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6",
            "MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.26"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "Image": "mysql:5.6.26",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/lib/mysql": {}
        },
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "NetworkDisabled": false,
        "MacAddress": "",
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    }
}
]
```

My dev enviroment:

- Windows 7 Pro
- Docker 1.7.0
- Boot2Docker-cli version 1.7.0
- MySQL container 5.6.26

Comment: Don't know about mysql usage within docker, but usually mysql by default only binds to 127.0.0.1 so you'll need to have it listen to 0.0.0.0 if you want external connections (unless that's already the default configuration when running under docker)

Comment: It appears it is as I mentioned. http://txt.fliglio.com/2013/11/creating-a-mysql-docker-container/

Comment: Did you try the [official mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) already?

Comment: Yes it's the official one.

Comment: As @ssnobody said the container was not listening to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for my is mapping the port when I created the container.

```
docker run --name YOUR_CONTAINER -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=YOUR_PASS -d mysql:5.6.26
```